# some queries regarding log4j settings?

Tags: java, log4j

I have below settings for log4j.properties. But all log text whether info,debug,exception,fatal goes to `MyDebugFile`. No file prefixed with exception is created.
My question  are:

1. Can I mention same file for log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE and log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE
2. What does property log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Threshold specify?
3. Why is the file prefixed with exception is not created?

#### Set up the format for messages logged to the Exception log file.

```
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Threshold=INFO
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Directory=C:/log/
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Prefix=exception.
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Suffix=.log
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{3} - %m%n
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB
 log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=4
```

#### Set up the format for messages logged to the debug log file.

```
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.Directory=C:/log/
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.Prefix=MyDebugFile.
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.Suffix=.log
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{3} - %m%n
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.MaxFileSize=100KB
 log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.MaxBackupIndex=4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can I mention same file for log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE and
   log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE

--> I don't think log4j really supports two appenders writing to the same file because of synchronization issues.

2 . What does property log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Threshold
    specify?

--> Read an article [here.](http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html)

3 . Why is the file prefixed with exception is not created?

--> For this I don't have any idea.

This should help you

log4j.rootLogger=EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE, DEBUG_LOG_FILE

## setup A1

log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.EXCEPTION_LOG_FILE.File=exception.log
...

## setup A2

log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.DEBUG_LOG_FILE.File=MyDebugFile.log

Comment: hi hardik. It would be great help if you can reply point wise.